# where to set xpages/ibmsbt proxy configuration

Tags: xpages, http-proxy, ibm-sbt

I have intranet based domino 9x (running windows) server sitting behind a firewall and proxy.  To make http/s requests via server side java I set the http/s.proxyHost and other jvm settings to allow my java.net calls.  Works fine when doing a simple GET via java.net classes, but fails when I attempt to use the ibmsbt ProfileService call (code works fine when outside our network).  Can anyone out there direct me to what is probably an obvious answer on where to configure the proxy settings (host, port, username, password)?  I've seen a few references to the manaaged-bean.xml file, but it seems it is associated with some debugging proxy, and doesn't have any settings for username/password that I'm aware of.

**SmartCloudFilesEndpoint config in faces-config:**

```
 <managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>smartcloud</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sbt.services.client.endpoints.SmartCloudFilesEndpoint
    </managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
<!-- Endpoint URL -->
<managed-property>
  <property-name>url</property-name>
  <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>serviceName</property-name>
  <value>SmartCloud</value>
</managed-property>
<!-- OAuth parameters -->
<managed-property>
  <property-name>appId</property-name>
  <value>XPagesSBT</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>credentialStore</property-name>
  <value>CredStore</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>requestTokenURL</property-name>
  <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getRequestToken</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>authorizationURL</property-name>
  <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/authorizeToken</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>accessTokenURL</property-name>
  <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getAccessToken</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>consumerKey</property-name>
  <value>xxxxxxxxxx</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
  <property-name>consumerSecret</property-name>
  <value>xxxxxxxxxx</value>
</managed-property>
```

Comment: can you please include some code snippet of what you are calling, so that I can comment as to what is going on.  are you using this in an agent? or core java in an xpage?

Comment: Making a call to the ProfileService to get a user's profile through the SBT's API.  Most of the code for the application lives in an OSGi plugin and is referenced through SSJS.

Answer (score 1):

SBT currently supports this for debug purposes. You can enable this by adding below property to you endpoint.

```
  <managed-property>
        <property-name>httpProxy</property-name>
        <value>IpOfProxy:PortNumberOfProxy</value>
    </managed-property>
```

If you need to enable this for all endpoint, just add this to you sbt.properties directly
sbt.httpProxy=127.0.0.1:8888

We do not support the credentials for now as this is not required by most of the proxies used for debugging like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Can you provide me more details of your environment and I can check if we can enhance the code to work in your environment.

Comment: All internet traffic gets routed through our internet/web proxies and requires authentication to pass through.

Comment: All internet traffic gets routed through our internet/web proxies and requires Active Directory authentication to pass through. (i.e. client/caller<-->proxy/firewall<-->internet).  Unfortunately this also includes server to server communications through to the internet.  I've already started the process with our security team to open up the firewall and bypass the proxy to gain access to https://apps.na.collabserv.com end point, but would rather not have to cycle through that lengthy process every time I need to integrate a server with the SmartCloud :)

Answer (score 0):

Try *Ports -> Proxies* in Server Document.